# How to rolling back Java 1.6.0_29 on Mac because of Memory Leaks

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm experiencing serious memory usage and elevated GC'ing on Mac after updating to the latest version of Java 1.6.0_29.  Prior to this update I had no problems with the stability of IntelliJ on the Mac.  In fact it was the stablest version I'd used, rock solid.  However, after this latest update I have been experiencing extreme lag due to excessive GC'ing.  Eventually it has to be restarted to clear out the memory.  I'd like to roll back to a prior version.  I tried looking in the Java Preferences panel, but the only version available is 1.6.0_29.  All my previous versions are missing.

There has been some evidence and bugs filed against Java 1.6.0_29, but I'd like to rollback given it'll take Apple months to release a new version.  And I'm concerned Apple won't fix it seeing as this was the last scheduled release of Apple supported Java on the Mac.

http://www.concurrentaffair.org/2011/11/14/drjava-definitionspanememoryleaktest-fails-on-mac/

So how do I roll back to a prior version of Java on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](http://wiki.oneswarm.org/index.php/OS_X_10.6_Snow_Leopard) post it is described how to download, unpack and install an older version of java. It is for java 5 but should work with any version.

I think this is the previous version but I haven't tried it. 
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Java/java_for_mac_os_x_10.7_developer_package/javadeveloper_for_mac_os_x_10.7__11a511.dmg. You need to be logged in to fetch it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off trying to change the garbage collector, and not G1GC which is horrible in a lot of situations (and may be one of the causes for the memory leak). You can tweak a lot of garbage collector options. See [here](http://piotrga.wordpress.com/2006/12/12/intellij-and-garbage-collection/) for more details.

Comment: The leak is actually in a Swing component which is used by all Swing applications so while a different GC algorithm might help it will still leak shrinking the available memory and require running GC too often.